# How can I run another command after running a server in a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I want to run another command after running a Node.js server from a shell script on an Ubuntu box, but the second command never launch.

```
node server.js
xdg-open index.html
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: There's a few ways to run node.js to act like a service. One option is to use [PM2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-18-04) which takes care of a lot of the technical bits so you don't have to write /etc/init.d or similar type scripts, or monkey with `nohup`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add into **start** in `package.json` >>

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js && xdg-open index.html"
  },
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  }
}
```

and run with **npm start**

see: [npm script](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts)